# Python - "map" a list of keys to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntax

I have a multidimensional dictionary in Python, and I have a list which has the keys that I want to access. What is the easiest way to get the value from the dictionary?

Example:

```
main = {
    'one': {
        'two': {
            'three': "Final word"
        }
    }
}

mylist = ['one', 'two', 'three']

# and I want to print out the value of `three` ("Final word")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loop over `mylist`, storing an intermediate dict (I called it `submain`) until you run out of `mylist` elements:

```
submain = main
for key in mylist:
    submain = submain[key]
print submain
```

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent to mhlester's solution, with a taste of functional programming:

```
import operator
print reduce(operator.getitem, mylist, main)
```